# Java 8 Stream filter with comparator

Tags: java, java-stream, comparator, predicate, apache-commons-collection

I want to filter list of `MyObject` based on `values` field. In this case: if any value on `MyObject::getValues` is less than given `value`, than the predicate is false. I haven't found the way to do it with Stream API, so I tried `ComparatorPredicate` by `Apache`. Here is my try:

```
private Predicate<MyObject> valueGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ValueObject value){
    return myObject -> myObject.getValues().stream()
            .noneMatch(v -> ComparatorPredicate.comparatorPredicate(value, new ValueComparator(), ComparatorPredicate.Criterion.LESS)
                    .evaluate(v));
}
```

This, however, results in:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Boolean to com.ValueObject
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1351)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.noneMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:459)
```

So my question is why does the ClassCastException occur and how to resolve it AND/OR how to resolve my problem with some other (better?) solution?

**UPDATE:**

A little update on the issue. The first problem (`ClassCastException`) was caused by the code I didn't include in my example. After solving it `ComparatorPredicate` works fine, so if you like it: go for it. I, however will go with the suggestion from accepted answer which is simpler and doesn't involve using external libs. Especially since `ComparatorPredicate` doesn't extend `java.util.function.Predicate` but `org.apache.commons.collections4.Predicate` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why you had to use `ComparatorPredicate.comparatorPredicate`.

How about:

```
private Predicate<MyObject> valueGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ValueObject value){
    ValueComparator comparator = new ValueComparator();
    return myObject -> myObject.getValues().stream()
            .noneMatch(v -> comparator.compare(v,value)<0);
}
```

This is assuming `ValueComparator` implements `Comparator<ValueObject>`.

Comment: It even works if `ValueComparator` does not implement `Comparator<ValueObject>`, as long as it has a `compare` method that does the expected thing.